# Owl carousel issue with last item when open a modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, owl-carousel

I have the next issue with OWL CAROUSEL. I am using a single item option and a auto play with stop on hover option. Inside of each item i am using a bootstrap button for opening a modal. The modal is outside the OWL CAROUSEL. Everything works ok until we get to last item of the carousel. When i press on the button the modal opens, if the slide changes ( because of the autoplay ) and i close the modal it brokes out. I also removed stop on hover, and after i open the last item modal the carousel stucks.

[You can see the replicated issue here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pv395/)

OWL CAROUSEL

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">MODAL</button>
    <img src="http://www.highsnobiety.com/files/2013/05/lamborghini-egoista-concept-car-9.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">MODAL</button>
    <img src="http://www.highsnobiety.com/files/2013/05/lamborghini-egoista-concept-car-9.jpg" alt="The Last of us">
  </div>
</div>
```

BOOTSTRAP STANDARD MODAL

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-   labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#owl-demo .item img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

#owl-demo .item button {
    position: absolute;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        navigation : false,
        autoPlay: 2200,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 800,
        singleItem : true,
        pagination: true,
        stopOnHover: true,

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following thing will fix this. First we must stop the carousel when the modal opens... then after we close the modal, we jump to next slide. This works on the last item also, because now it stops instead of returning to the first slide. Thank you Christina for the idea with stopping the carousel.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  owl.trigger('owl.stop');
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  owl.trigger('owl.next');
```

Answer (score 0):

**http://jsfiddle.net/pv395/6/**

```
.modal-open #owl-demo {width:100%!important;}
.modal-open #owl-demo .item {width:100%!important;}
```

This appears to do the trick. Let me know. I tested it and waited during the last slide for it to move and it ceased shifting. The thing is, you're no longer interacting with the slider when your modal is open so having it stop on hover is not what you need.

You need it to stop. Here's an idea that works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var owl = $("#owl-demo");

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        navigation : false,
        autoPlay: 2200,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 800,
        singleItem : true,
        pagination: true,
        stopOnHover: true,
    });

 $('#owl-demo .btn').click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.stop');
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex. I think the event when modal is closed should change to:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
   owl.trigger('owl.play',2200);
});
```

Note: Because if we use 'owl.next' => the Owl carousel will go to the next slide and STOP. But if we use 'owl.next' with autoPlay setting = 2200 so it would work like the first time we run it.